# SFTP Renci.SshNet Uploading file with the existing name - append or throw an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, sftp, ssh.net

I wonder what is the default behavior for `SftpClient.UploadFile` function of Renci.SshNet library if uploading file name exists in the directory (not using the method with override parameter)? Will it throw an exception or append the content to the existing file?

```
UploadFile(Stream input, string path, Action uploadCallback = null)
```

I could not find any clues in the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`SftpClient.UploadFile` overload without the `canOverride` argument](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET/blob/2016.1.0/src/Renci.SshNet/SftpClient.cs#L750-L768) behaves as if the argument were `true`.

```
public void UploadFile(Stream input, string path, Action<ulong> uploadCallback = null)
{
    UploadFile(input, path, true, uploadCallback);
}
```

What means that the file will be *overwritten* (so neither it will *throw an exception* nor it will *append* the file).

---

When `canOverride` is false, and the file already exists, the method will throw an exception.